# How to map two classes using Auto Mapper in c# when the destination class has object arrays

Tags: c#, automapper

Below is the mapper snippet with classes :

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
 {
   cfg.CreateMap<STest, ETest>().ForMember(d => d.customFields[0].stringValue, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.val));
 }
);

var result = Mapper.Map<ETest>(JsonDeseriazedSource);
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
```

And these are the source and destination classes to be mapped:

```
//source class
  public class STest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string val { get; set; }
    }

// destination class
  public class ETest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Customfield[] customFields { get; set; }
    }
  public class Customfield
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string fieldName { get; set; }
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to map stringValue in Customfield object(destination) from val in Stest(source).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Simple suggestion is not to use Automapper, in my experience you end up banging your head when auto configurations don't work or in any case you end up writing custom mappers. Not to suggest Automapper is a bad option if your mappings are straightforward, as it get complex, you lose the benefit of automapper.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar what other way would you suggest then?

Comment: I prefer to write extension methods for Entities to do the conversion explicitly, that way I know what is going on exactl, example: ToEntity(..) and ToResponseObject(...). It's more work but no magic. Works for both DTO coming in or going out from your API. Extension methods still allow you to follow SRP and keeping the entities clean and simple.

Comment: well, json request will be dynamic so explicit conversion may be an issue later.

Comment: Problem with dynamic type is you won't get a model of the response in your swagger, I try to use static types. But your usecase might be different.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                 {
                    cfg.CreateMap<STest, Customfield>()
                        .ForMember(d => d.stringValue, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.val));
                    cfg.CreateMap<STest[], ETest>()
                        .ForMember(d => d.customFields, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Select(Mapper.Map<Customfield>)));
                 });

var sTests= new[] { new STest { Id = "1", val = "val1" }, new STest { Id = "2", val = "val2" } };
var result = Mapper.Map<ETest>(sTests);
```

Comment: It doesn't work out. customfield object is still null after mapping :(

Comment: you have created an array of objects for  STest class but plz use a deserialized json body as a source to map